# IE7: click triggers only on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

I try to hide a div, when click on a checkbox:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function() {
  $("div.new").hide();
});
```

The hidding of the div occurs only after the mouse is off the checkbox, why? should I use mousedown for explorer?

Comment: How about `change` event?

Comment: @kidwon it's the same with the change event :/

Comment: Sorry all just seen the comments

Comment: What if you give the checkbox a class or call an id, does this work?

Comment: Btw: you can simplify `input[type='checkbox']` with `:checkbox` (same with `:text` and `:radio`). And you shouldn't use `tag.class` selectors, it is slower than just selecting `.class` (and in most cases not needed).

Comment: @CR41G14 That would make no difference.

Comment: @Simon Bad advice "*Because :checkbox is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :checkbox cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="checkbox"] instead.*" from the [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

Comment: @epascarello it wasn't an advice, just a hint. But thanks for the input.

Comment: Can't reproduce this with an emulator (having only IE10), but I'd recall both `radio` and `checkbox` had this "feature" in IE7. The best medicin would be to use mousedown as you've suggested already in your post. Or you could try with a wrapper...

Answer (score -2):

Try giving the checkboxes a class and call the function on that class

```
$(".checkbox").on('click', function() {
  $("div.new").hide();
});
```